# Start an activity as home screen wihtout setting it as MAIN in manifest

Tags: android

I have two activities MainActivity and DataActivity. My app is set as a home, i.e, it can be set so that when home is pressed my app should be opened. Currently MainActivity is returned when home is pressed. I want that only for the first execution of app everytime, DataActivity must be launcher and should never be called again. So if I set DataActivity's

```
android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"
```

this activity will be called everytime but it will also be called when home is pressed which I dont want.

I have tried to finish() DataActivity as soon as it is paused but that results in fc and I also get error saying onPause() couldnt be reached.

So what can I do that DataActivity is called once in beginning when app is launched without setting it as MAIN, HOME, DEFAULT, LAUNCHER in manifest.

Answer (score 0):

If you want some code to be called for the first time, it would be simplest to just check that yourself. You can check in you `MainActivty` if it was already launched before (how you do this depends on what really you do) and if you see it was already called, just start `DtaActivty` and `finish()` MainActivity from your `onCreate()` code

Comment: Well it is opposite. DataActivity starts MainActivity. So yeah I tired doing that by calling onPuase(){finish();} but then it gives me error saying onPuase cant be reached.

Comment: The proper method is `onPause()` not `onPuase()`. Also, for this particular case, killing the activity in `onCreate()` makes more sense.

Comment: Sorry that was typing mistake. So should I put the onPause() in onCreate only?

Comment: i would put it in onCreate() because the sunner you kill unwanted activity, the better. no point to wait

Comment: does it answer your question?

Comment: Sorry I had internet connectivity issues. Actually I tried to put it in onCreate() but it just force closes. Same error-didnt call through to super.onPause(). And one more thing is I dont have that line super.onPause() so why is it saying like that I dont understand

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier if you set one activity to be MAIN and have it open your other Activity (which I presume is some sort of configuration activity) the first time the app is launched. You can simply store a boolean in SharedPreferences on first launch and check for this value thereafter.

Comment: Yes I did that. As I told my app is default launcher. So if I do like this then when user presses home button, it goes to activity which is set as MAIN. I dont wan that.

Comment: Thats why i say make the one you DO want them to go to be MAIN and have it start the other one only when you want it to.

Comment: Yes I did this. I want the main activity to fetch data from an activity which hasnt been started yet so main activity is null at start and hence it gives me nullpointerexception